# VisualVM does not Start on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: java, ubuntu, visualvm, ubuntu-18.04

VisualVM does not start after installing it with `sudo apt install visualvm` on Ubuntu 18.04. It simply does nothing.

Starting it with `visualvm -J-Djava.util.logging.config.file=logging-jconsole.properties` yields the following error message:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no splashscreen in java.library.path
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
  at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
  at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
  at java.awt.SplashScreen$1.run(SplashScreen.java:124)
  at java.awt.SplashScreen$1.run(SplashScreen.java:122)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at java.awt.SplashScreen.getSplashScreen(SplashScreen.java:121)
  at org.netbeans.core.startup.Splash.<init>(Unknown Source)
  at org.netbeans.core.startup.Splash.getInstance(Unknown Source)
  at org.netbeans.core.startup.Main.start(Unknown Source)
  at org.netbeans.core.startup.TopThreadGroup.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

The problem persists after installing the JDK with `sudo apt install default-jdk`.

Comment: That looks like a bug in the Ubuntu package.  A library is missing, misnamed, in the wrong place, or something.  Report it via the Ubuntu LaunchPad tracker.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I figured it out myself. It had the wrong version of OpenJDK installed. The "default-jdk" package on Ubuntu seems to be the "headless" version (openjdk-8-jdk-headless). In order to get VisualVM to work I uninstalled the headless version of the OpenJDK and installed OpenJDK minus headless.

```
sudo apt remove openjdk-8-jdk-headless
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk
```